# How can I stop Windows 8.1 system tray icons from launching metro (Modern UI) apps?

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, notification-area, control-panel

I've installed Start Menu 8 and since Windows 8.1 boots to desktop, I'm able to avoid most of the Modern UI/Metro tablety stuff.

Unfortunately, there's one area where I'm thrown into PC Settings rather than Control Panel, and that's when I click on any icon in the system tray, be it networking or bluetooth, I'm tossed into the Modern UI PC Settings.

Is there any way to stop this short of disabling the system tray altogether and using taskbar shortcuts to Control Panel applets?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by controlling most of the system settings thru control panel, or right click on e.g. network icon and select Open Network Center, which brings up Control Panel

Indeed when you left-click on some icons on taskbar eg. network, metro bar will appear on  the right side of screen. And there is no way to avoid that, its hard coded.